# Farseer Physics Vector2 class

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

I'm trying to make an XNA game using Farseer Physics, and it's complaining that XNA and Farseer both have a class called Vector2.
How would I make it only use one of them?

Answer (score 2):

You shoud specify fully qualified namepsace name, or by making story shorter use somethign like this:

```
using farser = FarserPhysicsNamespace;
```

and in code use just

```
farser.Vector2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Farseer has a class called Vector2, at least I haven't faced this problem nor seen Vector2 class in it.

Quick Google search gave me [this link](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/61785.aspx), which is probably related to your problem. Basicly Farseer is excpecting another version of XNA framework. Are you using XNA 4.0 and the latest version of Farseer? You could also try latest source version from [here](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets).

Comment: I'm using XNA 4 and I got farseer from that same place.  The error is "Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2 [c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll]' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2 [c:\Users\Milo\Downloads\Farseer Physics Engine 3.3.1 Class (2)\Farseer Physics Engine 3.3.1 Class\bin\Debug\FarseerPhysics.dll]' C:\Users\Milo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\physics_test\physics_test\physics_test\Game1.cs 33 31 physics_test"

Comment: Can you run Farseer samples correctly? Can be downloaded from here: http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/releases/view/64108#DownloadId=226767 . I am not sure what is your problem may be, so I just have to recommend that you ask the same question on Farseer's official forums: http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/discussions . They can surely help you further!

Comment: I'm trying the farseer samples, but it says "A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly.

In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project.  Set the executable project as the startup project"

Comment: Maybe you only downloaded the Farseer Framework library and not the samples? Or maybe you have opened the former solution instead of the latter? Could you try to locate an executable project in the solution and set that as start project?

Answer (score 0):

Farseer comes with a vanilla class library that includes all of the relevant math classes and methods from Xna. Using the vanilla library will allow you to not have to include Xna in your project. It is useful for Mono or WinForms.

If you are using Xna then you will want to reference the Xna version of Farseer Physics.